# build folder doesn't update in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

I have a git hub repository for a Eclipse project.When I cloned that repo to my machine, build folder dose not have any classes. So I have clean the project and rebuild it. Then the classes are appear in project folder, but  Eclipse doesn't show. That project was a web service project, when I try to create that web service, following exception comes,

Exception occurred while reading or writing file D:\Eclipse\Workspace\Travel_Ceylon_Web_Service\build\classes (The system cannot find the path specified)

I was trying to create a axis2 web service. What will be the reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Highlighting the project folder in the Package explorer view and pressing F5, or right-clicking and navigating to Refresh will generally get eclipse to acknowledge that the file system has changed and it should update its view.

Sometimes for a more stubborn problem going to Project>Clean and then doing a refresh will "unstick" Eclipse.

The trouble seems to be that eclipse keeps a separate, virtual model of what's in the project folders on disk, and they don't always match.  They usually catch up with each other eventually, but manually refreshing speeds up the process, at least for most of the times I've seen a similar problem.

Comment: I did the steps you have highlighted many times. But Still doesn't work.

Comment: It could be a problem with how the project was imported.  If the repository isn't a full on Eclipse project, then sometimes it's best to start the project by importing it from git, instead of importing it from the filesystem.  Wish I could be of more help.

Comment: I think there is a bug with eclipse.

Comment: Another thing to try, although I know this was a long time ago, is to go to Window > Preferences, then General > Workspace and select "Refresh using native hooks or polling" and "Refresh on access"  Those options control when Eclipse 'notices' external file manipulations.